# Dispatching an event that starts bubbling from the same event handler?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, event-bubbling

Does anyone know any techniques to ensure that an event listener gets dispatched starting from the *same* event handler?

Here's an example:

```
form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  console.log('submitting');
});

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  if (form.getAttribute('submitting')) return true;

  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('submit');
    form.setAttribute('submitting', 'submitting');
    // some "re-submit" dispatch logic
    dispatch(form, 'submit');
  }, 0);
});

form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  console.log('submitted');
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

If you press the submit button, you'll get:

```
submitting
submit
submitting
submitted
```

This is not ideal, it'd be nice to be able to get:

```
submitting
submit
submitted
```

Since this will be part of a library, please assume you *cannot* modify the before and after event handlers.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML and possibly a jsFiddle? And where is the code for `dispatch`?